# Removing Ubuntu without losing Windows XP

Tags: windows, uninstall

I had a 160 GB hard disk with Windows XP. Then I installed Ubuntu 11.10 64bit. But I didn't knew anything about disk partition. After installation, I only have C drive with 20 GB in xp and about 40 GB in Ubuntu. I have  The Ubuntu in a DVD.

How do I remove it and get all the space back in Windows XP without losing XP?

Comment: How did you install it? wubi or dual boot

Comment: If Ubuntu is on a DVD, just remove the DVD. Nothing else to be done there.

Answer (score 2):

I think the fastest way is to use fixmbr from the Windows recovery console, [as in this example](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ht/repairmbr.htm).

After you manage to use Windows boot loader, just run Windows, and go to My Computer -> Managenent -> Disk Utility and format the linux partition to any file system you want (probably NTFS).

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

This solution will seem to be worked until you reboot your computer. **Do not try it.**

--> I realised that; that will probably remove grub and Windows will not be able to understand nor rewrite mbr data for "sure".

That means you will lose both OS.

> Open your XP.
>
> write `diskmgmt.msc` to "Run"
>
> Find your linux partition and delete it.
>
> Right click on C: partition. And select the option helps you include
>   the empty space in your disk.
>
> Hope This Helps. Tried on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I uninstalled Ubuntu back in the time where I didn't like it, and it damaged badly my Windows 7. Luckily, I had the repair disk.

In your case, you should just use a partition manager and delete the Ubuntu files (from Windows -- there is a default partition manager in the admin tools).

Thanks, mjchopperboy, hoping your XP will survive.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can use:

1. Download a trial of Acronis Disk Director, boot from the CD and increase the size of your partitions. [To download go here and click on free trial](http://www.acronis.eu/homecomputing/products/diskdirector/)
2. Keep Ubuntu installed after you change the partition sizes, and boot from the XP CD, choose repair console and once you get to the command prompt type `fixboot c:` (if c: is you xp boot drive) and that will make XP boot again.  If you want to get rid of Ubuntu, delete the Ubuntu partition from the Acronis CD, and then use the `fixboot` command.

Let me know if more help is needed.

Comment: I find it amusing that you suggest Acronis, given that OP has access to a Ubunu Live-CD which contains gparted. And `fixmbr` needsto be run in both cases.

Comment: touché,  That can be done too.  I just have spent more time with acronis and windows.